# How can I store and retrieve an array in ScriptProperties?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Inside the handler function bellow I'm trying to store and get the value of an array of arrays named "theses":

```
 var fact_list = [ ["Kennedy Inauguration", "politics", "tZwnNdFNkNklYc3pVUzZINUV4eUtWVWFSVEf"], ["Pericles’ Funeral Oration", "politics", "sdgrewaNkNklYc3pVUzZINUV4eUtW345ufaZ"], ["The Pleasure of Books", "culture", "1234rFszdgrfYc3pVUzZINUV4eU43usacd"], ["I Am The First Accused (Nelson Mandela)", "law", "34rsgadOsidjSZIswjadi95uydnfklsdks"] ];
function submit(e){
  Logger.log("running submit(e)"); 
  var numberOfItems = e.parameter.checkbox_total;
  var itemsSelected = [];
  // for each item, if it is checked / selected, add it to itemsSelected
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
    if(e.parameter['checkbox_isChecked_'+i] == 'true'){
      itemsSelected.push(e.parameter['checkbox_value_'+i]);
    }
  }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Logger.log("itemsSelected = " + itemsSelected);

  ScriptProperties.setProperties({'theses': itemsSelected}, true); 


  var thesesArrays = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses');
  Logger.log("thesesArrays = " + thesesArrays);
  for (var i = 0; i < thesesArrays.lenght(); i++){
       var thesesId = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][2];
       var thesesType = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][1];
       importTheses(target, thesesId, thesesType);
}       
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

But when the code gets the line `for (var i = 0; i < thesesArrays.lenght(); i++){` I got an error, because `thesesArrays` is not an array of arrays (as I intended) but an object which doesn't have the `lenght()` method.

How can I fix that? How can I store and retrieve an array in ScriptProperties?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In javascript, you can't do

```
array.length();
```

You need to delete the () because length() don't exist !

EDIT:

And if it's returning an array of array of object, you could do a function that transform the array of object into an array of your specific object by looping it, then create your object and setting it's properties like this for example:

```
this.name = object['name'];
```

Comment: As @ZigMandel pointed out, this answer only points out a small error (including missing the misspelling.)  More importantly, `setProperties()` doesn't support storing anything but a string.  Additionally, `ScriptProperties.setProperties()` and its affiliated static methods are no longer supported.

Answer (score 12):

The other answer only deals with the syntax error on length. But it still wont work because you can only store strings in scriptProperties.

1) json.stringify your array to store it as string

2) dont call getProperty a million times. Call it once before the loop and json.parse it into an array.

Comment: Thanks, @Zig Mandel, your comment was very usefull!

Comment: I would generally think that this is the "correct" answer to the stated question: in order to store an array in Google App Scripts properties, it must be stringified first. Thank you @zig-mandel.

Comment: yes @craftapprentice no idea why you marked the other one correct